# jQuery to select only specified number of elements

Tags: jquery, html, css, onclicklistener

`jQuery` to select only specified number of elements, onselect of more than specified then unselect the previously selected element.

I have the below code to restrict the selection of 4th image but i need to be able to click even if three are selected and when 4th image is selected the first image should be deselected.

### HTML

```
<pre>
    <ul class="ul-attribute80" style="margin-top: 10px;">
        <li class="swatchContainer">
            <img id="col-11" src="images/col1.jpg" class="swatch" alt="Skipper" width="30px" height="30px" title="Skipper">
        </li>
        <li class="swatchContainer">
            <img id="col-11" src="images/col1.jpg" class="swatch" alt="Skipper" width="30px" height="30px" title="Skipper">
        </li>
        <li class="swatchContainer">
            <img id="col-11" src="images/col1.jpg" class="swatch" alt="Skipper" width="30px" height="30px" title="Skipper">
        </li>
        <li class="swatchContainer">
            <img id="col-11" src="images/col1.jpg" class="swatch" alt="Skipper" width="30px" height="30px" title="Skipper">
        </li>
    </ul>
</pre>
```

### JS

```
var counter= 0;
jQuery(".ul-attribute80 li img").click(function() {
    if(counter < 3) {
        if(jQuery(this).hasClass("selected")) {
            jQuery(this).removeClass("selected");
            count--;
        } else {
            jQuery(this).addClass("selected");
            count++;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: IDs **must** be unique and in your jQuery you use count instead of counter.

Comment: sorry id and counter thats a typo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of a counter I'd use an array. Just add the elements to the array as you click, checking to see if they're already in the array or the array is longer than three elements.

```
var selected = [];
jQuery(".ul-attribute80 li img").click(function () {
    $('.swatch').removeClass("selected");
    if ($.inArray($(this).attr('id'), selected) == -1) {
        selected.push($(this).attr('id'));
    } else {
        selected.splice($.inArray($(this).attr('id'), selected), 1);
    }
    if (selected.length > 3) {
        selected.shift();
    }
    $.each(selected, function () {
        $('#' + this).addClass("selected");
    })
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/zxH72/)**